# Relative layout hidden behind Recycler view

Tags: android

I am trying to put my progress screen (`@+id/progressScreen`) on top of my recycler view (`@+id/cardList`) but for some reason the recycler view always comes on top and hides it. I've tried `View.bringToFront()` but it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    tools:targetApi="LOLLIPOP">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
             >

        </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#30FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/progressText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/progressbar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry .I read it wrong. You should first put your RelativeLayout for  `android:id="@+id/progressView"` on top of the RecyclerView and then add **android:translationZ** param to correct Z index because you are using 3dp elevation for the RV. Therefore, to be on top of the RecyclerView `android:translationZ="4"`

Here is the fixed code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    tools:targetApi="LOLLIPOP">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
            android:translationZ="4dp"
            android:background="#30FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/progressText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/progressbar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

        </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>


    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The previous answer was not fully correct, because you only wanted to display @+id/progressScreen on top of RV and I moved the RV below the @+id/progressScreen. Please check the last edited code, it should be now correct and display @+id/progressScreen on top of the RV.